# Unable to initialize Printer in windows command prompt

Tags: php, shell, command-line, epson

I have installed Epson TM82II printer on my Windows 7 and i want to print simple text file.

My system is showing  Printer name EPSON TM-T82II Receipt and my file path is c:\happy.txt.

I have tried `PRINT c:\happy.txt /D:EPSON TM-T82II Reciept` in command prompt but it gives error

```
Unable to initialize EPSON.
```

Comment: possibly duplicate. take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line